# Advent of Code 2015: day 5, part 2 unknown false positives

Tags: rust

I'm working through the Advent of Code 2015 problems in order to practise my Rust skills.

Here is the problem description:

Realizing the error of his ways, Santa has switched to a better model of determining whether a string is naughty or nice. None of the old rules apply, as they are all clearly ridiculous.

Now, a nice string is one with all of the following properties:

- It contains a pair of any two letters that appears at least twice in the string without overlapping, like `xyxy` (`xy`) or `aabcdefgaa` (`aa`), but not like `aaa` (`aa`, but it overlaps).
- It contains at least one letter which repeats with exactly one letter between them, like `xyx`, `abcdefeghi` (`efe`), or even `aaa`.
  For example:

`qjhvhtzxzqqjkmpb` is nice because is has a pair that appears twice (`qj`) and a letter that repeats with exactly one letter between them (`zxz`).

`xxyxx` is nice because it has a pair that appears twice and a letter that repeats with one between, even though the letters used by each rule overlap.

`uurcxstgmygtbstg` is naughty because it has a pair (`tg`) but no repeat with a single letter between them.

`ieodomkazucvgmuy` is naughty because it has a repeating letter with one between (`odo`), but no pair that appears twice.

How many strings are nice under these new rules?

This is what I've managed to come up with so far:

```rust
pub fn part2(strings: &[String]) -> usize {
    strings.iter().filter(|x| is_nice(x)).count()

    /* for s in [
        String::from("qjhvhtzxzqqjkmpb"),
        String::from("xxyxx"),
        String::from("uurcxstgmygtbstg"),
        String::from("ieodomkazucvgmuy"),
        String::from("aaa"),
    ]
    .iter()
    {
        is_nice(s);
    }

    0 */
}

fn is_nice(s: &String) -> bool {
    let repeat = has_repeat(s);
    let pair = has_pair(s);
    /* println!(
        "s = {}: repeat = {}, pair = {}, nice = {}",
        s,
        repeat,
        pair,
        repeat && pair
    ); */

    repeat && pair
}

fn has_repeat(s: &String) -> bool {
    for (c1, c2) in s.chars().zip(s.chars().skip(2)) {
        if c1 == c2 {
            return true;
        }
    }

    false
}

fn has_pair(s: &String) -> bool {
    // Generate all possible pairs
    let mut pairs = Vec::new();
    for (c1, c2) in s.chars().zip(s.chars().skip(1)) {
        pairs.push((c1, c2));
    }

    // Look for overlap
    for (value1, value2) in pairs.iter().zip(pairs.iter().skip(1)) {
        if value1 == value2 {
            // Overlap has occurred
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Look for matching pair
    for value in pairs.iter() {
        if pairs.iter().filter(|x| *x == value).count() >= 2 {
            //println!("Repeat pair: {:?}", value);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // No pair found
    false
}
```

However despite getting the expected results for the commented-out test values, my result when running on the [actual puzzle input](https://pastebin.com/hDrnA01M) does not compare with community verified regex-based implementations. I can't seem to see where the problem is despite having thoroughly tested each function with known test values.

I would rather not use regex if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think `has_pairs` has a bug:

In the word `aaabbaa`, we have overlapping `aa` (at the beginning `aaa`), but I think you are not allowed to `return false` right away, because there is another - non-overlapping - `aa` at the end of the word.